# Invoke Windows 8 Maps application from WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, bing-maps

I am working on WPF application. I have a requirement where I have longitude and latitude of source and destination location. Now I want to invoke Windows 8 Maps application with lat, long of source and destination location and want Windows 8 maps to start navigation from source towards destination.

I have seen many examples which use Windows Bing Map control and WPF application and show route. My requirement is navigation, so it gives me directions step by step.

Comment: I tried this. It draw path but not navigation. http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/rahul4_saxena/draw-route-between-current-location-and-destination-on-googl/

Comment: Do you want the step by step directions in text form or to draw them on the Maps control?

Comment: Should be like google map navigation app on android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can launch the Windows 8 Maps App from a WPF app, however there is no turn by turn navigation available in the Windows 8 map app.

To launch the Windows 8 map app from WPF you can use the protocol activation URL's available for the map app. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/jj635237.aspx

By creating a URL that starts with bingmaps:// and putting it in a web browser address bar you can launch the app and perform a few functionalities which are documented in the above URL.

You can then open this URL from a WPF like this:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("bingmaps:?rtp=adr.Paris~adr.London&sty=a&trfc=1");
```

Comment: How can i pass longtitude and latitude values?

Comment: Thanks again. I used pos instead of adr and pass latitude and longitude values and it worked great.